# I have hard time to webscrape values that are both in <span> and outside <span>

Tags: web-scraping

I am using scrapy to scrape this website https://www.coop.se/butiker-erbjudanden/coop-butiker/coop-lilla-edet/ . I am trying to retrieve the values that are shown in the picture. But I believe I am webscraping the values in a bad way, see my variable called "Info". Please give me some tips of how I should actually webscrape the values in the picture. [image]

The code I use today is:

```
 categories = response.css("body > main > div.js-childLayoutContainer.u-marginTmd > div > div.js-favoriteStoreView.js-settings > div.Main-container.Main-container--padding > div:nth-child(4) > div")
    for category in categories:
        if category.css("div.Grid-cell.u-sizeFull.u-marginVxsm > h2::text").extract_first() == "Butikens bästa erbjudanden denna vecka":
            continue
        else:
            Category = category.css("div.Grid-cell.u-sizeFull.u-marginVxsm > h2::text").extract_first()
            
         
            items = category.css("div > article > div")
            for item in items:

                Product = item.css("div.ItemTeaser-info > h3::text").extract_first()
                if not Product:
                    Product = None
                else:
                    Product


                Info = item.css("p.ItemTeaser-description").extract_first()      
                Info = Info.replace("<br>","")
                Info = Info.replace('<div class="">',"")
                Info = Info.replace("</div>","")
                Info = Info.replace("</p>","")
                Info = Info.replace("<p>","")
                Info = Info.replace("</span>","")
                Info = Info.replace('<p class="ItemTeaser-description">',"")
                Info = Info.replace('<span class="ItemTeaser-brand">',"")
                Info = Info.strip()
                Info = " ".join(Info.split())
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an xpath using `product.xpath('.//p[@class="ItemTeaser-description"]/text()')`. The result will be a list of selector with the text

For example:

```py
import scrapy

class ShopSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "shopspider"
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.coop.se/butiker-erbjudanden/coop-butiker/coop-lilla-edet/']

    def parse(self, response):
        for product in response.css('.ItemTeaser-info'):
            yield {
                'title': product.xpath('.//h3/text()').get(),
                'description': "".join([
                    t.get().strip()
                    for t in product.xpath('.//p[@class="ItemTeaser-description"]/text()')
                ])
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I will try it out, but I guess then my way is ok also? Or is it bad practice?